# Updating tensorflow in Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I see I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.0 and I get errors like:

```
keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
```

I'm guessing my version is outdated but I can't seem to find out how to update Tensorflow in Anaconda? I'm coding in a Jupyter notebook.

Clicking "apply" here does not update it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activate conda-environment
```

then

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

> The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

*Above error simple say that you are using an old method   *

```
get_default_graph
# find into your code replace with  

compat.v1.get_default_graph instead
```